# Is there a way to know if PlaySound() has finished playing a WAV file?

Tags: winapi, audio, playsound

I need to play one or more `.wav` files in sequence, based on user input. Is there a callback function I could use to find out if the file has finished playing?

I found an example here: [How to know if a music file has finished playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760712/), but that is for some coco2dx, whatever that is.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

```
PlaySound(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_WAVE1), GetModuleHandle(NULL), SND_RESOURCE);
```

Edit 2:
I said in other posts asking assistance for my app that I would post a download link of a working copy of the application [My Blood Pressure](http://bcbhelper.com) If you download, you will encounter bugs, it is no where near finished, there is a zip and exe version to download

Edit: using a timer with estimated time of play for my purposes is not a best fit solution, I already tried that, it worked but could not rely on reliability of doing it this way.

I found this in the link suggestion of dsp_user

```
MMRESULT waveOutGetPosition(
  HWAVEOUT hwo,
  LPMMTIME pmmt,
  UINT     cbmmt`
```

Just need to now know how or if it will work for me, maybe a thread that monitors the play function in my component that plays the sound file.

Would something like this help ?

```
// Global variables. 

HANDLE hData  = NULL;  // handle of waveform data memory 
HPSTR  lpData = NULL;  // pointer to waveform data memory 
 
void WriteWaveData(void) 
{ 
    HWAVEOUT    hWaveOut; 
    HGLOBAL     hWaveHdr; 
    LPWAVEHDR   lpWaveHdr; 
    HMMIO       hmmio; 
    UINT        wResult; 
    HANDLE      hFormat; 
    WAVEFORMAT  *pFormat; 
    DWORD       dwDataSize; 

    // Open a waveform device for output using window callback. 

    if (waveOutOpen((LPHWAVEOUT)&hWaveOut, WAVE_MAPPER, 
                    (LPWAVEFORMAT)pFormat, 
                    (LONG)hwndApp, 0L, CALLBACK_WINDOW)) 
    { 
        MessageBox(hwndApp, 
                   "Failed to open waveform output device.", 
                   NULL, MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION); 
        LocalUnlock(hFormat); 
        LocalFree(hFormat); 
        mmioClose(hmmio, 0); 
        return; 
    } 
 
    // Allocate and lock memory for the waveform data. 
 
    hData = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE | GMEM_SHARE, dwDataSize ); 
    if (!hData) 
    { 
        MessageBox(hwndApp, "Out of memory.", 
                   NULL, MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION); 
        mmioClose(hmmio, 0); 
        return; 
    } 
    if ((lpData = GlobalLock(hData)) == NULL) 
    { 
        MessageBox(hwndApp, "Failed to lock memory for data chunk.", 
                   NULL, MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION); 
        GlobalFree(hData); 
        mmioClose(hmmio, 0); 
        return; 
    } 
 
    // Read the waveform data subchunk. 
 
    if(mmioRead(hmmio, (HPSTR) lpData, dwDataSize) != (LRESULT)dwDataSize) 
    { 
        MessageBox(hwndApp, "Failed to read data chunk.", 
                   NULL, MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION); 
        GlobalUnlock(hData); 
        GlobalFree(hData); 
        mmioClose(hmmio, 0); 
        return; 
    } 
 
    // Allocate and lock memory for the header. 

    hWaveHdr = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE | GMEM_SHARE, 
        (DWORD) sizeof(WAVEHDR)); 
    if (hWaveHdr == NULL) 
    { 
        GlobalUnlock(hData); 
        GlobalFree(hData); 
        MessageBox(hwndApp, "Not enough memory for header.", 
            NULL, MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION); 
        return; 
    } 
 
    lpWaveHdr = (LPWAVEHDR) GlobalLock(hWaveHdr); 
    if (lpWaveHdr == NULL) 
    { 
        GlobalUnlock(hData); 
        GlobalFree(hData); 
        MessageBox(hwndApp, 
            "Failed to lock memory for header.", 
            NULL, MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION); 
        return; 
    } 
 
    // After allocation, set up and prepare header. 
 
    lpWaveHdr->lpData = lpData; 
    lpWaveHdr->dwBufferLength = dwDataSize; 
    lpWaveHdr->dwFlags = 0L; 
    lpWaveHdr->dwLoops = 0L; 
    waveOutPrepareHeader(hWaveOut, lpWaveHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR)); 
 
    // Now the data block can be sent to the output device. The 
    // waveOutWrite function returns immediately and waveform 
    // data is sent to the output device in the background. 
 
    wResult = waveOutWrite(hWaveOut, lpWaveHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR)); 
    if (wResult != 0) 
    { 
        waveOutUnprepareHeader(hWaveOut, lpWaveHdr, 
                               sizeof(WAVEHDR)); 
        GlobalUnlock( hData); 
        GlobalFree(hData); 
        MessageBox(hwndApp, "Failed to write block to device", 
                   NULL, MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION); 
        return; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: no, but you can use the wave api to accomplish this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/). It's a lot more work though.

Comment: @dsp_user, there seems to be lots of choices available, will explore and try out a couple of potentials, cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detect when the sound has finished playing when using PlaySound in Win32 SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934059/how-do-i-detect-when-the-sound-has-finished-playing-when-using-playsound-in-win3)

Comment: @#Remy, I tried that a couple of days ago, it did work but concluded that it was not a best fit solution, there is the SND_SYNC, am about to give that a go but I am thinking that because it does return until sound is done, may be an inconvenience to user who would not have the ability to interrupt.  Will also look at the function that returns play position.  Cheers

Comment: There is a [MEEndOfStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/meendofstream) event [a media source](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/27ffb0811ca761741502feaefdb591aebf592193/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/wavsource/WavSource.cpp#L1519) would trigger. See [Sample Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/writing-a-custom-media-source#sample-requests) for more information.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT, Thank you for that, will try out the sample media source sample code.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**waveOutGetPosition** can be used to get the current playback position but it will not tell you when the playback has completed and you would still have to call it in a loop , which is not efficient.  I suggest that you process the **MM_WOM_DONE** message (this message is sent every time when a buffer with samples has been processed). In order to get sent a MM_WOM_DONE, you need to open your device with a **CALLBACK_WINDOW** flag and a window handle, which you have already done.

```
waveOutOpen((LPHWAVEOUT)&hWaveOut, WAVE_MAPPER, 
                    (LPWAVEFORMAT)pFormat, 
                    (LONG)hwndApp, 0L, CALLBACK_WINDOW);
```

You can then map a callback function to process **MM_WOM_DONE** in your VCL code by using a macro

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(MM_WOM_DONE, TMessage, ProcessDoneMsg)
END_MESSAGE_MAP(TForm)
```

Your callback might look something like this

```
void  __fastcall TForm1::ProcessDoneMsg(TMessage& doneMsg)
{
    WPARAM wp = doneMsg.WParam; //handle to device (HWAVEOUT )
    LPARAM lp = doneMsg.LParam; //pointer to the buffer that's been played

   //typically you will have to unprepare the buffer that's just been played and prepare a new wave header (new buffer) for playback
   waveOutUnprepareHeader((HWAVEOUT)wp, (LPWAVEHDR)lp, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

  //prepare new header for playback (provide a new buffer for playback)
    waveOutPrepareHeader((HWAVEOUT)wp, (LPWAVEHDR)pNewHeader, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
  
  //do whatever processing is neccessary
}
```

Note that I'm not even calling **waveOutGetPosition** because that's not really necessary unless you need the current playback position.

Still, there are things that you have to do as well. When you're dealing with large files, you will typically need to create multiple smaller buffers that will hold your wave file samples (you can store these buffers in a std::vector ). It makes sense to create your buffers relatively small (8kB or so) because that means that your app will be able to process consistently both small and large wave files. In fact, having a very large buffer that can hold an entire file means that your app is more likely to experience "running out of memory" errors.

One final thing, **waveOutOpen** requires that you parse the wave file and return a pointer to a **WAVEFORMATEX** structure but you're currently not doing that. I suggest that you use a library to parse the wave file because there's hardly any point in trying to do it manually.

For smooth playback, your app needs to start with 2 buffers instead of just 1, which means 2 calls to **waveOutPrepareHeader** and **waveOutWrite** respectively. For every buffer that's been processed/played, your callback will be called and that's where you prepare a new buffer (call to **waveOutPrepareHeader**) so that you always have 2 buffers prepared.

UPDATE:

I've written a complete console application demnostrating how to play 2 files one after another. It's not perfect and there's a problem with **waveOutReset** so I wasn't able to stop the playback while still playing (I've never had a problem with this API on my other computer so perhaps you won't have this problem either). The wave file parser supports most common wave formats including WAVE_FORMAT_PCM (8 bit/16 bit) as well as WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT.

The code

```
main.cpp

#include "wavefilereader.h"
#include "winwaveplayer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QCoreApplication>

void PlaybackComplete();

bool playbackComplete = false;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    const std::string wave2 = "C:\\test\\wav\\Ring03.wav";//Ring03

    const std::string wave1 = "C:\\test\\wav\\M1F1-uint8-AF.wav";

    WaveFileReader wfReader;

    if(wfReader.Open(wave1) == 0){

        wfReader.PrintWaveInfo();

        WAVEDATA waveData;
        waveData.pSamples = wfReader.GetSamples();
        waveData.size     = wfReader.GetDataSize();
        waveData.wfex     = wfReader.GetWaveformatStruct();

        WinWavePlayer wavePlayer(&waveData);
        //register the callback to notify main() when the current track has been completed
        wavePlayer.SetPlaybackComplete(&PlaybackComplete);

        wavePlayer.StartPlayback(); //this both opens the device for playback and starts playback
        /* uncomment this to test pausing/resuming playback (this part works ok)
        Sleep(2000);
        wavePlayer.PausePlayback();
        Sleep(1000);
        wavePlayer.ResumePlayback();
        */
        //calling this stops the playback but the method waveOutReset never returns (it should return immediately)
        //Sleep(2000);
        //wavePlayer.StopPlayback();
        while( true ){
            if( playbackComplete )
                break;
        }
        cout << " first track complete " <<  endl;
        wavePlayer.CloseDevice();

        wfReader.FreeResources();
        //playback complete - start another file
        if(playbackComplete  && wfReader.Open(wave2) == 0){ //wfReader object can be reused, no need to create another instance
            wfReader.PrintWaveInfo();
            //reassign WAVEDATA to new values, rather than create a new struct
            waveData.pSamples = wfReader.GetSamples();
            waveData.size     = wfReader.GetDataSize();
            waveData.wfex     = wfReader.GetWaveformatStruct();
            cout << " playing wave 2 " << playbackComplete << endl;
            playbackComplete  = false;
            WinWavePlayer wavePlayer2(&waveData);

            wavePlayer2.SetPlaybackComplete(&PlaybackComplete);

            wavePlayer2.StartPlayback();
            //wait for it to finsish
            while( true ){
                if( playbackComplete )
                    break;
            }
            wavePlayer2.CloseDevice();

            wfReader.FreeResources();

        }
    }
    return a.exec();
}
//callback
void PlaybackComplete(){
    playbackComplete = true;
    cout << " playback complete callback main called " << endl;

}
```

wavefilereader.h

```
#ifndef WAVEFILEREADER_H
#define WAVEFILEREADER_H

#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//this structure is mapped to the beginning of a wave file
typedef struct  {
    char chunkId[4];   //"RIFF"
    unsigned int chunkSize;
    char format[4];  //"WAVE"
    char subChunkId[4]; //"fmt"
    unsigned int subChunkSize; //sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX)
    WAVEFORMATEX wfex;

} WAVE_HDR, *PWAVE_HDR;

struct WaveParser{

    bool CheckWaveHeader(const char * const);

    bool IsFmtSection(const char * const );

    bool IsDataSection(const char * const );

    bool FillWaveFormatStruct(const char * const, unsigned );

    char* GetAudioSamples(char * const, unsigned);

    const WAVE_HDR& GetWaveHeader(){
        return waveHdr;
    }

    unsigned int GetDataSize(){
        return dataSize;
    }

private:
        WAVE_HDR waveHdr;

        unsigned fmtOffset; //offset to the fmt section (where a WAVEFORMATEX is located)

        unsigned dataOffset; //offset to the actual samples ( found in .data section)

        unsigned dataSize; //size of the audio samples

        char *   pSamples;

};
class WaveFileReader
{
        WaveParser      waveParser;
        char*           pData;
        unsigned int    fileSize;
        std::string     fileName;
        char*           pSamples;

public:
    WaveFileReader(){}

    ~WaveFileReader(){
        FreeResources();
    }
    void FreeResources(){

    if(pData)
        delete [] pData;
    }
    unsigned Open(const std::string &fName);

    char* GetSamples(){ return pSamples; }

    WaveParser GetParser(){ return waveParser; }

    unsigned int GetDataSize(){ return waveParser.GetDataSize(); }

    bool IsFormatSupported();

    const WAVEFORMATEX& GetWaveformatStruct(){
        return waveParser.GetWaveHeader().wfex;
    }
    void PrintWaveInfo();

    std::string GetFormatDesc( );

    unsigned GetNumSamples(){

          return  waveParser.GetDataSize() / (waveParser.GetWaveHeader().wfex.wBitsPerSample/8);
    }
};

#endif // WAVEFILEREADER_H
```

wavefilereader.cpp

```
#include "wavefilereader.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

bool WaveFileReader::IsFormatSupported(){

    const WAVEFORMATEX& wfex = GetWaveformatStruct();
    const short format = wfex.wFormatTag;
    const short bitsPerSample = wfex.wBitsPerSample;

    switch(format){
        case 0x0003:
            return true;  //32 BIT FLOAT
        case 0x0001:
            return (bitsPerSample ==  8)  ? true :
                   (bitsPerSample == 16)  ? true :
                                            false;
        default:
            cout <<  "unsupported wave format: " << format << endl;
            return false;
    }
}
std::string WaveFileReader::GetFormatDesc( ){

    const WAVEFORMATEX& wfex = GetWaveformatStruct();
    const short format = wfex.wFormatTag;//pWaveFormat->wfex.wFormatTag;
    const short bitsPerSample = wfex.wBitsPerSample;

    switch(format){
        case 0x0003:
            return std::string("WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT - 32 bit float");  //32 BIT FLOAT

        case 0x0001:
            return (bitsPerSample ==  8)  ? std::string("WAVE_FORMAT_PCM - 8 bit unsigned byte")    :
                   (bitsPerSample == 16)  ? std::string("WAVE_FORMAT_PCM - 16 bit signed short") :
                                            std::string("unrecognized wave format");

        default:
            cout <<  "wave format: " << format << endl;
            return std::string("unrecognized wave format");
    }
}
bool WaveParser::IsFmtSection(const char * const pData){

    const char fmt[3] = { 'f','m','t' };
    for(int i=0; i<3;i++){
        if(pData[i]!= fmt[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
bool WaveParser::IsDataSection(const char * const pData){

    const char data[4] = { 'd','a','t','a' };
    for(int i=0; i<4;i++){
        if(pData[i]!=data[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
bool  WaveParser::FillWaveFormatStruct(const char * const pData, unsigned fileSize)
{
    const unsigned  fmtSectionSize  =  8;
    const unsigned  cAdvancePtr     =  2;//when moving the pointer by 2 bytes we'll never miss a section
    const unsigned  cWaveFormatSectionOffset = 12;

    const char* const pStartFile     = pData;
    const char      *pEndFile       = pData + fileSize;
    const char      *pMovingPtr     = pData;
    //this is usually the correct offset to the fmt section but if sections like list, fact etc exist, we need to  find the location where the fmt chunk begin (it can't be hardcoded)
    pMovingPtr += cWaveFormatSectionOffset;

    while(pMovingPtr < pEndFile){
        if(IsFmtSection(pMovingPtr)){ //we've found the fmt section
            fmtOffset = pMovingPtr - pStartFile ;
            pMovingPtr += fmtSectionSize;
            pEndFile = pMovingPtr;
            waveHdr.wfex = ( WAVEFORMATEX& )*pMovingPtr;
            return true; //waveformex found and filled
        }else{
            pMovingPtr += cAdvancePtr;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
char* WaveParser::GetAudioSamples(char * const pData, unsigned int fileSize){

        const unsigned  cStep         =  2;
        const unsigned  cDataSize  =  4;
        const unsigned  cSectionSize  =  8;

        const char * const  pStartFile = pData;
        const char *        pEndFile = pData + fileSize - fmtOffset;
        char *              pMovingPtr = pData;

        pMovingPtr += (fmtOffset + cDataSize);

        while(pMovingPtr < pEndFile){
            if(IsDataSection(pMovingPtr)){
                pMovingPtr += cSectionSize; //we've found the data section
                pEndFile = pMovingPtr;
                dataOffset = pEndFile-pStartFile;
              //  dataSize  = *(unsigned int*)(pMovingPtr-cDataSize); //the size in bytes of the samples
                dataSize  = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(pMovingPtr-cDataSize); //the size in bytes of the samples
            }else{
                pMovingPtr += cStep;
            }
        }
        return pMovingPtr;
}
bool WaveParser::CheckWaveHeader(const char* const pHdr){

    const char  riffSection[]  { 'R','I','F','F' };//this section starts at offset 0
    const char  waveSection[]  { 'W','A','V','E' }; //this starts at offset 8

    const unsigned riffLen    = sizeof(riffSection);
    const unsigned waveLen    = sizeof(waveSection);
    const unsigned riffOffset = 0;
    const unsigned waveOffset = 8;

    for(int i=0;i<riffLen;i++){
            if(pHdr[riffOffset+i]!=riffSection[i])
                return false;
        }
    for(int i=0;i<waveLen;i++){
            if(pHdr[waveOffset+i]!=waveSection[i])
                return false;
        }
    return true;
}
unsigned WaveFileReader::Open(const std::string &fName){

    ifstream file (fName.c_str(), ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);

    if (file.is_open())
      {
        file.seekg (0, ios::end);
        fileSize = file.tellg();
        //for large files we would ideally create multiple buffers but you can probably get away with this for your use case
        pData = new char[fileSize];

        file.seekg (0, ios::beg);

        file.read (pData, fileSize);

        //file not a wave or invalid format
        if(!waveParser.CheckWaveHeader(pData)){
           cout << "error parsing wave - invalid wave file!" << endl;
           return -1;
        }

        if(!waveParser.FillWaveFormatStruct(pData, fileSize)){
            cout << "error parsing wave - cant find fmt/waveformatex section (possibly invalid wave file)!" << endl;   
            return -1;
        }
        if(!IsFormatSupported()){
            cout << "wave format not supported!" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
        if((pSamples = waveParser.GetAudioSamples(pData, fileSize)) == nullptr){
           cout << "error parsing wave - can't find data section (possibly invalid wave file)!" << endl;;
            return -1;
        }
        //ok we have a valid wave file
        return 0;
      }else{
        cout << "error opening input wave file - check that the path is correct!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
void WaveFileReader::PrintWaveInfo(){

    const WAVEFORMATEX& wfex = this->GetWaveformatStruct();

    cout << "WAVEFORMATEX structure"    << endl;
    cout << "format description:   "    << this->GetFormatDesc() << endl;
    cout << "sample rate:  "            << wfex.nSamplesPerSec << endl;
    cout << "bit depth:    "            << wfex.wBitsPerSample << endl;
    cout << "number of channels:   "    << wfex.nChannels << endl;
    cout << "number of samples:   "     << this->GetNumSamples() << endl;
    cout << "totatl samples size:   "   << this->GetDataSize() << endl;
}
```

winwaveplayer.h

```
#ifndef WINWAVEPLAYER_H
#define WINWAVEPLAYER_H

#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <windef.h>

using namespace std;

//function pointer to notify our main thread
typedef void ( *PlaybackCompleteFp )( );

typedef struct{
 WAVEFORMATEX wfex;
 char *pSamples;   //pointer to the actual samples
 //for multiple buffers you'd have something like std:vector<char*> vSamples instead, this would require somewhat more complicated code
 unsigned int size; //size of pSamples buffer
}WAVEDATA, *PWAVEDATA;

class WinWavePlayer
{
        WAVEHDR whdrFirst;//struct for  buffer 1

        WAVEHDR whdrSecond;//struct for buffer 2

        HWAVEOUT hWaveOut;

      //  MMTIME mmTime; //this would be needed if were to get the current playback position

        bool isPlaying = false, isCompleted = false, isPaused = false, firstBuffer = false;

        unsigned int waveBufferSize, dataOffset;

        const char * pSamples;

        PWAVEDATA pWaveData;

        //function ptr to notify the main thread
        PlaybackCompleteFp funPtrPlaybackComplete;

        int PrepareSingleBuffer(bool);

        int PrepareBuffers();

        int OpenPlayback();


public:
        WinWavePlayer() : dataOffset(0), waveBufferSize(1024*8){}

        WinWavePlayer(const PWAVEDATA p) : pWaveData(p), dataOffset(0), waveBufferSize(1024*8) {}

        void SetPlaybackComplete(PlaybackCompleteFp fp){
            funPtrPlaybackComplete = fp;
        }

        int PausePlayback();

        int StartPlayback();

        int StopPlayback();

        int ResumePlayback();

        int CloseDevice();

        void SetWaveData(const PWAVEDATA p){
            pWaveData = p;
        }

        static  void WaveCallback(HWAVEOUT, UINT, DWORD_PTR, DWORD_PTR, DWORD_PTR);

        static  std::string GetWaveError(MMRESULT);

};

#endif // WINWAVEPLAYER_H
```

winwaveplayer.cpp

```
#include "winwaveplayer.h"
#include <iostream>


void CALLBACK WinWavePlayer::WaveCallback(HWAVEOUT hWaveOut, UINT msg, DWORD_PTR pInst, DWORD_PTR param1, DWORD_PTR param2){
    //WOM_DONE is sent when either a buffer has been played or waveOutReset  called

    if(msg == WOM_DONE){ //we're interested in WOM_DONE only
        WinWavePlayer *pInstance = reinterpret_cast<WinWavePlayer*>(pInst);
        WAVEHDR       *pWhdr     = reinterpret_cast<WAVEHDR*>(param1);

        waveOutUnprepareHeader(hWaveOut, pWhdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

        if( pInstance->isCompleted && !pInstance->isPlaying){ //Stop playback clicked
            return;
        }
        if(pInstance->isCompleted ){   //if a track has reached the end, stop the playback and set the flag to false
            pInstance->funPtrPlaybackComplete();//notify main() that we're done playing
            return;
         }
        if(pInstance->dataOffset + pInstance->waveBufferSize >= pInstance->pWaveData->size)
         {  //playing the last buffer
            //set isCompleted to true and return immediately so that we don't try to prepare new playback buffers
            //one last buffer will still be played though, so this callback will be hit one more time
            cout << "playing last buffer" << endl;
            pInstance->isCompleted = true;
            return;
          }
        //alternate between the playback buffers so that the audio device never runs out of data
        if (!pInstance->firstBuffer){
             pInstance->PrepareSingleBuffer(true);
        }else{
             pInstance->PrepareSingleBuffer(false);
        }
   //  cout << "callback 3" << endl;
        MMRESULT mm = pInstance->firstBuffer ?
                    waveOutWrite(hWaveOut, &pInstance->whdrSecond,  sizeof(WAVEHDR)) :
                    waveOutWrite(hWaveOut, &pInstance->whdrFirst,   sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        if (mm != MMSYSERR_NOERROR){
              cout << GetWaveError(mm) << endl;
        }
        pInstance->firstBuffer = !pInstance->firstBuffer;
    }
}
int WinWavePlayer::CloseDevice(){

  //  MMRESULT mm = waveOutReset(hWaveOut);

    MMRESULT mm = waveOutClose(hWaveOut);
    if(mm != MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
         cout << "close device: " << GetWaveError(mm) << endl;
    return mm;
}
//this should be called only after the track has been paused by a call to PausePlayback
int WinWavePlayer::ResumePlayback(){

        MMRESULT mm = waveOutRestart(hWaveOut);
        isPlaying = true;
        isPaused  = false;
        return mm;
}
int WinWavePlayer::PausePlayback(){

        MMRESULT mm = waveOutPause(hWaveOut);
        isPlaying = false;
        isPaused = true;
        return mm;
}
int WinWavePlayer::StopPlayback(){

    //reset variables
    isCompleted = true;
    isPlaying =   false;
    firstBuffer = false;

    waveBufferSize = 1024*8;  //8kB default buffer size
    dataOffset = 0;
    //this never returns and it should return immediately , don't know why
    MMRESULT mm = waveOutReset(hWaveOut);
    cout << "stop completed is never printed" << endl;
    funPtrPlaybackComplete();//callback to main()

    return mm;
}
int WinWavePlayer::StartPlayback(){

        MMRESULT mm;

        mm = OpenPlayback();

        if (mm != MMSYSERR_NOERROR){
            cout << GetWaveError(mm) << endl;
            return mm;
        }

        mm = waveOutWrite(hWaveOut, &whdrFirst,  sizeof(WAVEHDR));

        mm = waveOutWrite(hWaveOut, &whdrSecond, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

        isPlaying = true;
        isCompleted = false;

        return mm;
}
int WinWavePlayer::OpenPlayback(){

    MMRESULT mm;
    //open the device for playback -- the actual playback won't start until we call waveOutWrite
    //since this is a console application, we can't use  WINDOW_CALLBACK, we're using CALLBACK_FUNCTION instead
    cout << "open playback1" << endl;
    mm = waveOutOpen(&hWaveOut, WAVE_MAPPER, &pWaveData->wfex, reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(&WaveCallback), (DWORD_PTR)this, CALLBACK_FUNCTION);

    if(mm != MMSYSERR_NOERROR){
        cout << GetWaveError(mm) << endl;
        return mm;
    }

    mm = PrepareBuffers();
    return mm;
}
int WinWavePlayer::PrepareBuffers(){

    cout << " data offset: " << pWaveData->size << " " << waveBufferSize << endl;
    if(dataOffset + waveBufferSize > pWaveData->size ){
        waveBufferSize =  pWaveData->size - dataOffset;
    }

    whdrFirst.lpData = pWaveData->pSamples;
    whdrFirst.dwBufferLength = waveBufferSize;
    whdrFirst.dwFlags = 0;

    MMRESULT mm = waveOutPrepareHeader(hWaveOut, &whdrFirst,  sizeof(WAVEHDR));

    //prepare second buffer
    dataOffset += waveBufferSize;

    if(dataOffset + waveBufferSize > pWaveData->size )
        waveBufferSize =  pWaveData->size - dataOffset;

    whdrSecond.lpData = pWaveData->pSamples + dataOffset;
    whdrSecond.dwBufferLength = waveBufferSize;
    whdrSecond.dwFlags = 0;

    /*since our samples are stored a single buffer (pSamples), we dont really have to use 2 (sub)buffers but dividing our large buffer
    into smaller (sub)buffers makes sense because WaveCallback will be called more often and this is useful when we have to e.g notify
    the main thread of the playback position etc
    in this particular case our buffers point to different regions of the same main samples buffer
    (i.e. wHdrFirst->lpData/whdrSecond->lpData are always readjusted in calls to PrepareBuffers and PrepareSingleBuffer respectively)*/
    mm = waveOutPrepareHeader(hWaveOut, &whdrSecond, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

    return mm;
}
int WinWavePlayer::PrepareSingleBuffer(bool first){

    MMRESULT mm;
    if(dataOffset + waveBufferSize >= pWaveData->size ){
           waveBufferSize =  pWaveData->size - dataOffset;//we're running out of samples, so lets just take what's left
    }else{
         dataOffset += waveBufferSize;
    }

    WAVEHDR * const pWhdr  = first ? &whdrFirst : &whdrSecond;

    pWhdr->dwBufferLength = waveBufferSize;
    pWhdr->lpData = pWaveData->pSamples + dataOffset;
    pWhdr->dwFlags = 0;

    mm = waveOutPrepareHeader(hWaveOut, pWhdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

    return mm;
}
std::string WinWavePlayer::GetWaveError(MMRESULT mm)
{
        std::string errorMsg;
        switch (mm) {
            case MMSYSERR_INVALHANDLE:
                errorMsg = "Wave exception: Invalid handle";
                break;
            case MMSYSERR_NOMEM:
                errorMsg = "Wave exception: Not enough memory";
                break;
            case MMSYSERR_NODRIVER:
                errorMsg = "Wave exception: No driver present";
                break;
            case WAVERR_UNPREPARED:
                errorMsg = "Wave exception: Unprepared buffer";
                break;
            case MMSYSERR_HANDLEBUSY:
                errorMsg = "Wave exception: Handle busy";
                break;
            case MMSYSERR_ALLOCATED:
                errorMsg = "Wave exception: Device already allocated";
                break;
            case WAVERR_BADFORMAT:
                errorMsg = "Wave exception: Unsupported wave format";
                break;
            case MMSYSERR_INVALPARAM:
                errorMsg = "Wave exception: Invalid parameter";
                break;
            case WAVERR_STILLPLAYING:
                errorMsg = "Wave exception: Still playing";
                break;
            default:
            errorMsg = "Wave exception: Unknown error: Code " + to_string(mm);

        }
        return errorMsg;
}
```

You should be able to use this in a VCL forms application pretty much unmodified. Note that I'm still putting my file in a single buffer (in a WaveFileReader) so this can be certainly improved.

Comment: Thanks dsp_user, this looks good, I am hoping that I can get away with small intuitive chunks in files, so makes sense to use smaller buffers, but I have not done these types of things, will attempt to do this tomorrow. cheers

Comment: @OutOfTime, I've added some additional info. to my post.

Comment: I am keen to get my project and component set out into the open source universe but have not ever used or know how to go about doing that, there is widespread interest by medico professionals and home users alike in having MBP out on the global stage before my time is up, the principle of the system, is to be able to take the USB to your doctors office where it is plugged in and all information relating to the patient in the last x number of observation records as well as body diagram flag points where medical events may have been experienced, for coding I use the chaos method!!

Comment: The chaos method allows me to not worry about the right or wrong way of writing code only that the idea can be made to work and I think I have achieved that, any advice on getting this to the open source community would be extremely appreciated, cheers

Comment: @OutOfTime, "github" is the place for open source projects. If you need more information, I suggest that you ask a question about that on Quora , rather than here on SO.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, I have been attempting to get my head around this and tried to get some code going loosely but have to admit I do not know enough on the subject to get it going, never done anything in audio before so may have to go back to the timer method and hope for the best,  thanks for assistance, cheers

Comment: @OutOfTime, I'll write some code for you that doesn't depend on external libraries for parsing wave files so you can check back here in a day or two.

Comment: cheers for that, looking forward to that, if all is well will incorporate and acknowledge your code into my TSQLiteAgent which is the backbone of the component suit I have. If you have not yet downloaded a copy of the system go to bcbhelper.com cheers

Comment: thank you for putting time in for me, very much appreciated, will begin integrating the code into my agent within the next day or so, I will keep you informed. cheers